# Get-AzCloudServicePublicIPAddress returning nothing despite being visible from portal and other commands

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services, azureportal

I have a Cloud Service (Extended Support) on Azure and want to retrieve the associated public IP address from an Azure script. However when I run

```
Get-AzCloudServicePublicIPAddress -CloudServiceName $serviceName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -verbose
```

Nothing seems to happen at all. Moreover, when I run a swap command, i.e.

```
Switch-AzCloudService -CloudServiceName $serviceName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Confirm:$false
```

it is successful and I can see the public IP address for both the services in the output logging! Obviously I don't want to have to call this command to retrieve the IP address.

How do I get the IP information from powershell using the `Az` powershell module module?

Answer (score 0):

***Need to check:***

- Make sure that you are executing it in correct Azure tenant or subscription. Otherwise, it will not retrieve the exact output. Set azure subscription to the current one.

```
   select-Azuresubscription -subscriptionId <subscriptionID>
```

- Check for the existence of public IP addresses if there are any configured public Ip addresses under a given cloud service.
- Cloud Service commands support cloud service (extended support) only. check once whether you are trying to retrieve the same.

Simply you can use below Az CLI command to retrieve the IP configuration:

```bash
az network public-ip show -g <ResourceGroup> -n <publicIP>
```

[image]

***Or***

```bash
az network public-ip list
```

[image]

Comment: Given that I said that a swap operation works from Powershell with the public IP addresses clearly visible in the logs isn't it a given that Cloud Service (ES) is already set up correctly? Does `Get-AzCloudServicePublicIPAddress` work for you?

Comment: Not working in PowerShell as well as CLI also. Showing that get cloud service commands are under development maintenance.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. At any rate I have raised and issue on Github and Azure seems to think it's a problem on their side:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/20755

Comment: That is the one I am trying to explain you. It’s under development from Azure Side. Thanks!